# Dataset comes to Empty

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I want to get the values into Datset, my codes are as following

```
 public DataSet GetMemberById(int memberId)
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cnn = new SqlCommand("selectmemberByID", con))
                {
                    cnn.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cnn.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                    cnn.Parameters["@id"].Value = memberId;

                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cnn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cnn);
                            da.Fill(ds);

                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["MemberId"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                int memberId=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MemberId"]);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = utility.GetMemberById(memberId);
                GdMember.DataSource = ds;
                GdMember.DataBind();
                //txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            }
        }
```

in last method it shows me an error there is no table in the dataset.

```
stored procedure:

Alter proc [dbo].[selectmemberByID]
(
@memberId int=2
)
as 
begin
select * from dbo.MemberDetail
where id=@memberId
end
```

Comment: Don't call `ExecuteNonQuery` ! The stored procedure is executed and the data is fetched when you call `da.Fill(ds)` already. No need to call this twice!

Comment: sir it still shows an error.

Comment: Can you **show us** the complete error message??

Comment: Sir it throws an exception as follows: The IListSource does not contain any data sources.

Comment: And when you debug your code - where **exactly** does this error happen? Inside this procedure you're showing?

Comment: @Abhishekgupta - Try `GdMember.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you tried with below code instead of using "@Id"

```
cnn.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@memberId", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data adapter then what is the need to open the connection ? . Also check if the parameter is passing to your sp correctly or not.